# Load 100 UIImages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, asihttprequest

I am busy with an iPhone application. A part of it I load 100 small images from Flickr as an UIButton.
The problem is how to handle the memory. it loads around 5-6 mb each time. When I dealloc the view trough navigationController popViewController the memory stays almost the same.

What I do now is loop all the images and put the request to an ASINetworkQueue. When the loop is ready I do [networkQueue go].

```
//Loop images
for (NSDictionary* message in output)
{
    NSString *imageURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg", [message objectForKey:@"farm"], [message objectForKey:@"server"], [message objectForKey:@"id"], [message objectForKey:@"secret"]];

    if(cx > 280) { cy = cy + 78; cx = 6.0f; }

    //user data for the request
    NSMutableDictionary *imageInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //init Image
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(cx, cy, 72.0f, 72.0f);
    UIButton *myImage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setTag:i];

    [myImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; //grayColor
    [imageInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] forKey:@"arrayNr"];
    [images addObject: myImage];
    [fotoView addSubview: myImage];

    //get url
    NSURL *imageURI = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageURL];

    //load image
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: imageURI];

    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[message objectForKey:@"id"]]];
    [request setUserInfo: imageInfo];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    [imageURL release];
    [imageURI release];

    [myImage release];
    [imageInfo release];

    cx = cx + 78;
    i++;
}
```

When the request is finished I do this:

```
- (void)imageFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[request downloadDestinationPath]];
    if (img)
    {
        //set image
        UIButton *myButton = [images objectAtIndex:[[[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"arrayNr"] intValue]];
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:img forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    [img release];
}
```

And this is my dealloc function:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
    networkQueue.delegate = nil;
    [networkQueue release];

    [flickrController cancelAllOperations];
    flickrController.delegate = nil;
    [flickrController release];

    [images release];
    [fotoView release];
    [output release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I don't understand way the memory doesn't go away.
Solution what i can think about are:
- create an own object for the uibutton/uiimage.
- Use an UITableview to handle the images

Both solution I don't see how it would clear all the memory after closing the view.
Hope someone give me a heads-up how to handle this kind of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you posted the code where you do the cleanup, it might be clearer where the problem is, but I'm taking a guess anyway:

In the `imageFetchComplete:` method you retain the reference to the image when you invoke `setBackgroundImage:` It will therefore be kept in memory until you release the particular button object that retained it. Since the button itself is being retained by the `images` array, you would either need to release this array too, or in case of a mutable array remove the button from the array.

Comment: I put the rest of the code in my first post. What I did try was something like this at -(void)dealloc but it failed.

 for (UIButton* button in images)
 {
  [[button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] release];
  [button removeFromSuperview];
  [button release];
 }

Comment: Is the dealloc method being called?

Comment: I was like why you ask that question. It's normal that dealloc get called. But it doesn't get called. So I got the problem now. Hope to find a solution for it

Comment: @Marko, it is normal that dealloc get called if you have correctly ballanced the use of retain/release. But, since dealloc doesn't get called, you need to figure out where that extra retain sneaked in.

Comment: I almost never use retain. I now disabled most of the code and step by step I activate it again till the dealloc method isn't getting called again. Thanks for your help